fluentd output to s3 failed
I was trying to put logs produced by an application on docker-compose to my s3 bucket using fluentd, but got the following error
fluentd          |   2024-07-04 09:01:48 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluent-plugin-s3-1.3.0/lib/fluent/plugin/out_s3.rb:456:in `rescue in check_apikeys'    
fluentd          |   2024-07-04 09:01:48 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluent-plugin-s3-1.3.0/lib/fluent/plugin/out_s3.rb:451:in `check_apikeys'
fluentd          |   2024-07-04 09:01:48 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluent-plugin-s3-1.3.0/lib/fluent/plugin/out_s3.rb:240:in `start'
fluentd          |   2024-07-04 09:01:48 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.14.6/lib/fluent/root_agent.rb:203:in `block in start'
fluentd          |   2024-07-04 09:01:48 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.14.6/lib/fluent/root_agent.rb:192:in `block (2 levels) in lifecycle'
fluentd          |   2024-07-04 09:01:48 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.14.6/lib/fluent/root_agent.rb:191:in `each'
fluentd          |   2024-07-04 09:01:48 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.14.6/lib/fluent/root_agent.rb:191:in `block in lifecycle'
fluentd          |   2024-07-04 09:01:48 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.14.6/lib/fluent/root_agent.rb:178:in `each'
fluentd          |   2024-07-04 09:01:48 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.14.6/lib/fluent/root_agent.rb:178:in `lifecycle'
fluentd          |   2024-07-04 09:01:48 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.14.6/lib/fluent/root_agent.rb:202:in `start'
fluentd          |   2024-07-04 09:01:48 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.14.6/lib/fluent/engine.rb:248:in `start'
fluentd          |   2024-07-04 09:01:48 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.14.6/lib/fluent/engine.rb:147:in `run'
fluentd          |   2024-07-04 09:01:48 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.14.6/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:720:in `block in run_worker'
fluentd          |   2024-07-04 09:01:48 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.14.6/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:971:in `main_process'
fluentd          |   2024-07-04 09:01:48 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.14.6/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:711:in `run_worker'
fluentd          |   2024-07-04 09:01:48 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.14.6/lib/fluent/command/fluentd.rb:376:in `<top (required)>'
fluentd          |   2024-07-04 09:01:48 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
fluentd          |   2024-07-04 09:01:48 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
fluentd          |   2024-07-04 09:01:48 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.14.6/bin/fluentd:15:in `<top (required)>'
fluentd          |   2024-07-04 09:01:48 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/bin/fluentd:23:in `load'
fluentd          |   2024-07-04 09:01:48 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/bin/fluentd:23:in `<main>'
fluentd          | 2024-07-04 09:01:48 +0000 [error]: #0 unexpected error error_class=RuntimeError error="can't call S3 API. Please check your credentials or s3_region configuration. error = #<Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied: Access Denied>"
fluentd          |   2024-07-04 09:01:48 +0000 [error]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
fluentd          | 2024-07-04 09:01:48 +0000 [error]: Worker 0 finished unexpectedly with status 1

to write the configuration file for the output to s3 i followed the github guide of the s3 plugin:
<match pattern>
  @type s3

  aws_key_id x
  aws_sec_key x
  s3_bucket x
  s3_region x

  path logs/${tag}/%Y/%m/%d/
  s3_object_key_format %{path}%{time_slice}_%{index}.%{file_extension}

  # if you want to use ${tag} or %Y/%m/%d/ like syntax in path / s3_object_key_format,
  # need to specify tag for ${tag} and time for %Y/%m/%d in <buffer> argument.
  <buffer tag,time>
    @type file
    path /var/log/fluent/s3
    timekey 3600 # 1 hour partition
    timekey_wait 10m
    timekey_use_utc true # use utc
  </buffer>
  <format>
    @type json
  </format>
</match>

I double checked the spelling of my bucket, of the availability zone and of the keys, everything is correct.
What am I missing?

To get more context maybe adding more data regarding the s3 buckets and objects you want to access and where you run that code.
Maybe checking access to the S3 from the execution environment with the configured credentials manually by yourself would be a good start.

The use case is having as input logs collected by an nginx instance and using fluentd to send them on s3. The collection part is fine; I have no problem sending them to an elasticsearch-kibana instance running on containers on the same machine.
I followed your advice and checked on my AWS account, and this particular couple of keys appears to be used, so AWS receives the request with that IAM user associated, but I have no idea why fluentd says that the request is not authorized. The permission is configured to be able to PutObject in every directory of the bucket

Solved: fluentd requires a set of permissions beside the simple PutObject: it requires PutObject, GetObject, ListBucket and ListBucketVersions
